# Flask + Gunicorn + NGINX Static files?

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, nginx-config

Having some trouble serving static files (CSS + JS) with NGINX and Flask.
Current setup has the Flask website running in one container and NGINX running in another.
Static files are stored at `/static` within the Flask app directory.

How can I allow NGINX Container to access the CSS and JS files?

Flask Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.8-slim

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY . .
```

NGINX Dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.15.8

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY project.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

NGINX Project.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name gunicorn_nginx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://Website:8000;

        # Do not change this
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        root /Website/; 
    }
}
```

I have tried looking through some tutorials online but they don't seem to cover this aspect.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** It seems that by removing

```
location /static {
    rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
    root /Website/; 
}
```

from the project.config file Gunicorn is able to serve static files?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and removing the static location with alias solved the problem of not loading

I still dont understand why.

Comment: Will have a look at this and get back to you. Let me see if I can figure this out.

Comment: I already figured it out. I had a typo in the nginx alias.